# MongoDB save function not being entered by program

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following module,

```
module.exports.registerUser = (userData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (userData.password !== userData.password2) {
            reject("Passwords do not match!");
        }
        console.log(userData); //prints correctly
        let newUser = new iUser(userData);
        console.log(newUser); //prints correctly
        newUser.save((err) => {
            console.log("REACHED"); //DOES NOT ENTER
            if (err) {
                reject(err.code === 11000 ? 'Username already taken!' : 
                    `Error creating User: ${err}`);
            } else {
              console.log(newUser);
              resolve(newUser);
            }
            process.exit();
          });
    })
};
```

For some reason, the `.save()` is never invoked and line 10 is never reached... any thoughts?

---

### Edit:

With the `registerUser()` module, my `data-service-auth.js` source file so far is:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    "userName": {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    "email": String,
    "password": String,
    "loginHistory": {
        "userAgent": String,
        "dateTime": Date
    }
  });
  let iUser;

  module.exports.initialize = () => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let db = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://user:pass@ds237409.mlab.com:37409/web322_a6");
    db.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("error!");
        reject(err);
    });
    db.once('open', function() {
        console.log("enteringgggggggggggg");
        iUser = mongoose.model("iUser", userSchema);
        resolve();
    });
    resolve();
    });
};

module.exports.registerUser = (userData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (userData.password !== userData.password2) {
            reject("Passwords do not match!");
        }
        console.log(userData);
        let newUser = new iUser(userData);
        newUser.save((err) => {
            console.log("REACHED"); //DOES NOT ENTER
            if (err) {
                reject(err.code === 11000 ? 'Username already taken!' : 
                    `Error creating User: ${err}`);
            } else {
              console.log(newUser);
              resolve(newUser);
            }
            process.exit();
          });
    })
};
```

My register form POSTs to my `server.js` file, which has a route,

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    dataServiceAuth.registerUser(req.body).then((data) => {
        res.render('register', {successMessage: "User Created"});
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
        res.render('register', {errorMessage: err, userName: req.body.userName});
    })
});
```

And my `register.hbs` view is, (apologies if formatting is terrible, new coder here):

```
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <hr />
    <form method="post" action="/register">
        {{!-- form --}}
    </form>
    {{#if errorMessage }}
    <div class="alert">
    <strong>Error:</strong> {{errorMessage}}</div>
    {{else if successMessage}}
    <div class="success">
        <strong>Success:</strong> {{successMessage}}
    </div><a class="btn-right" 
        href="/login">Proceed to Log in</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br /> 
    {{/if}}
```

I assume it has to be the `.save()` function, because `console.log("REACHED");` is never reached and executed, however calls to `console.log(userData)` or `console.log(newUser);` after that instance is created yield expected results.

Comment: Is this mongodb's driver or mongoose? It looks like mongoose. If it's mongoose, add the mongoose tag

Comment: we need to see iUser code not here

Comment: @JoeWarner I've updated my original post with more information, thank you